# Find all occurrences of a specific character in a string between parentheses, which is after another string itself (REGEX)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to replace `/` with a `.` using Regex (and Atom Editor) so that `$app->call( 'text/'. $var .'/e );` becomes `$app->call( 'text.'. $var .'.e );`

But with no luck so far, here is what I came up with:

```
(?<=\()[^)]?[\/]+(?=\))
```

For some reason it only catches the forward slash when it's the only character of the string: https://regex101.com/r/zgPl5F/1

What am I missing here?

My idea is to target a specific class to bulk edit parameters passed to its functions (in Atom Editor) so that `$app->xxx(*/*)` becomes `$app->xxx(*.*)` (where xxx is always a function name). So altogether:

```
^(\$app->\w)+(?<=\()[^)]?[\/]+(?=\))
```

Edit: based on @Wiktor's answer I tried this, but it does not work:

```
^(\$app->\w)+(\/(?=[^()]*\)))+
```

NB. It's not exactly the same question.

Comment: [`\/(?=[^()]*\))`](https://regex101.com/r/Tw9yp6/1)?

Comment: wow, it works! Can submit this answer with a bit of details so I can understand what you're doing and accept your answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a very common workaround, I explained it already in another answer of mine: *`(?=[^()]*\))` - it is followed by 0 or more characters other than `(` or `)` (with `[^()]*`) and a literal `)`.*

Comment: i did not find this topic (i searched for 2hours), sorry. How could I prepend this regex with $app->xxx (where xxx are function names)? I tried to add `^(\$app->\w+)` but it does not seem to work. Idea is to target `/` when they are passed as parameters in a specific class. Your help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Ok, good, so the question was edited. However, I am not sure you can do aynything better in Atom. In Notepad++ and SublimeText (and I guess PhpStorm, though not sure), you could use `(?:\G(?!\A)|^\$app->\w+\()[^()]*?\K\/(?=[^()]*\))`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/yUH9Lc/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is brilliant! Your assumption was correct: if works using Notepad++, but not with Atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following solution in Notepad++ or SublimeText:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|^\$app->\w+\()[^()]*?\K/(?=[^()]*\))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yUH9Lc/1).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!\A)|^\$app->\w+\()` - end of a previous match (`\G(?!\A)`) or (`|`) start of a line, `$app->`, 1+ word chars and `(` (see `^\$app->\w+\(`)
- `[^()]*?` - 0 or more, but as few as possible, chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `/` - a slash
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - followed with 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`.